# Want to submit data from a form as a new Object in a JSON array using Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js

I am looking to create a simple input box with a submit button that will add information to a  JSON file. I am using Angular to retrieve that data, create a new JSON object and post this object with the new data to a file called pets.json.

HTML

```
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="PetPosting">
Enter text and hit enter:
<input type="text" ng-model="text" name="text" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Angular JS

```
  var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'bootstrapLightbox']);

 //load images from pets.json and display them in HTML
 app.controller('GalleryCtrl', function ($scope, Lightbox, $http) {
     $http.get('pets.json')
     .then(function(res){
      $scope.images = res.data;
   });
 });
 /*Add new data to JSON file*/
 app.controller('PetPosting',function($scope, $http) {

      $scope.submit = function() {
        if ($scope.text) {
          $http({
                    method: "post",
                    url: "pets.json",
                    data: {
                      "thumbUrl": $scope.text,
                    }
                });
        }

      }



});
```

I don't understand fully how this works. Any insight or direction on how to figure out how to do this simple task would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Do you get any error in console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not the correct implementation of "$http", the "url" property is a server endpoint that receives your Data, for that you would need some server-side code to append to the .json file.

If your wanting to save information Local to the user the LocalStorage API maybe sufficient and is very easy to implement